# How to exit a child process when another child finishes

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork

I'm developing a script to benchmark and compare programs written in a variety of languages (Perl, Java, R) designed to same purpose. I need to run two subroutines at same time, one to use Unix TOP command and another to execute programs. I'm trying to use Parallel::ForkManager. Here the piece of code i'm using to fork:

```
sub parallelRun{

$commands[0]= sub{topExec};
$commands[1]= sub{masExec};

my $manager = new Parallel::ForkManager( 2 );

for($i=0; $i <= $#commands; $i++) {

        $pid = $manager-> start and next;
        push(@pid,$pid);
        $commands[$i]();
        $manager-> finish;

    } # For End

    $manager->wait_all_children;
    $manager-> finish($pid[0]);
    undef(@pid);

} # Sub End
```

I need to finish `topExec()` (the TOP execution) when `masExec()` finishes, however the script is hanging after TOP command.

Bonus question: Is there a way to get system pid of the program executed in `masExec()` to track it in TOP command? Now, i'm tracking from columns user and command in Unix Top command (sub topExec).

Sorry for any language errors (non native in both ;) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`kill(TERM => $pid[0]);`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html)

---

By the way, I don't see why you're using P::FM here. You don't even need to create two children.

```
use POSIX qw( _exit );

sub parallelRun {
    my $pid = fork();
    die if !defined($pid);

    if (!$pid) {
       topExec();
       _exit(0);
    }

    masExec();
    kill(TERM => $pid);
    waitpid($pid, 0);
 }
```

---

A few Perl tips:

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. You have many undeclared variables, for starters.

1. ```
   $commands[0]= sub{topExec};
   $commands[1]= sub{masExec};
   ```

   should be

   ```
   my @commands = ( \&topExec, \&masExec );
   ```

   (Declare the array, don't create needless anonymous subs.)
2. ```
   for(my $i=0; $i <= $#commands; $i++) {
       ... $commands[$i] ...
   ```

   should be the simpler

   ```
   for my $i (0..$#commands) {
       ... $commands[$i] ...
   ```

   or even

   ```
   for my $command (@commands) {
       ... $command ...
   ```
3. ```
   undef(@pid);
   ```

   is completely unneeded. It's a symptom of not having properly declared `@pid`.